# Exception Title: Check if object is Null

Tags: c#, .net

I created table `N_Roles_Users` in my database, I want to show it's value if username matches with existing login user.

I wrote this code below. But it is generating exception that check if object is Null.

```
// currentUser="UserA";
public List<string> GetUserRoles( string currentUser)
{
        N_Roles_Users allroles = new N_Roles_Users(); //N_Roles_Users is database table name. 
        List<string> roleslist = new List<string>();
        List<char> temp = new List<char>();
        temp = allroles.user_name.ToList();
        List<char> tempa = new List<char>();
        tempa = allroles.role_name.ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
        {
            if (currentUser == temp[i].ToString())
            {
                roleslist.Add(tempa[i].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(tempa[i].ToString());
            }
        }

        return roleslist;
}
```

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: on which line you are getting the error

Comment: On which line is the exception generated? Please provide us with the stacktrace and exact exception type `System.InvalidOperationException` or maybe a `System.NullReferenceException` or what kind of exception?

Comment: what is user_name ? it's any method or property ?

Comment: on all lists. i removed list one by one to check that which list is creating this issue, but on each list this Exception generates. I executed queries to check it out that are values present in table or not. Values were present. I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: You make a new instance of `N_Roles_Users`, what is in the constructor? do you initialize everything?

Comment: @RameshRajendran It is Column Name in N_Roles_Users

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh . I think that column name return null (empty) values , so you get this error. please look my answer , check that condition or check that column has any values there ? ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RameshRajendran yes you are right, Now how to solve this?

Comment: See my answer . Check that condition : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18353979/2218635

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = allroles.user_name.ToList(); is the line of exception i guess.
```

set `allroles.user_name = "some value"` before

this line

```
temp = allroles.user_name.ToList();
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hello Zoya. What do you mean by shows nothing. Nothing is printed on console or what ?

Comment: yes, i wrote textbox1.Text=temp[1].ToString(); ... But nothing printed

Answer (score 0):

Check this condition

// currentUser="UserA";

```
public List<string> GetUserRoles( string currentUser)
        {
        N_Roles_Users allroles = new N_Roles_Users();
        List<string> roleslist = new List<string>();
        List<char> temp = new List<char>();
         **if(allroles.user_name.ToList()!=null &&  allroles.user_name.ToList().Count!=0)
          {
         temp = allroles.user_name.ToList();
         }**
        List<char> tempa = new List<char>();
        tempa = allroles.role_name.ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
            {
            if (currentUser == temp[i].ToString())
                {
                roleslist.Add(tempa[i].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(tempa[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        return roleslist;
        }
```

Comment: if `user_name` is null you will still get an NRE here